# Is it possible to upgrade from Windows-7 32-bit to Windows-7 64bit without losing data in Bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, mac, 64-bit, boot-camp, 32-bit

I want to install Windows-7 on a recent Mac Book Pro.
I have a Windows-7 (32-bit) installation disc that I plan to use for the installation, using Bootcamp.
However, I'm also thinking about getting a 64 bits version of the OS installation disc in a near future, because it is said to make a better use of the hardware.

If I install Windows-7 (32-bit) today and start to work with it, will I be able to upgrade to Windows-7 (64-bit) later ? 
when upgrading, is there a risk I could lose my previous work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont be able to upgrade in-place, however you can use Windows Easy Transfer to keep your files and some settings for a new install:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer

Comment: Just to add emphasis, this is a restriction of Windows itself and nothing to do with Bootcamp. You cannot upgrade 32- to 64-bit on PC hardware either.

Comment: Thanks Shevek, small world isn't it? :)

Comment: Thanks both for the answer and the additional information.